# Alterar coluna padrão DataTables JS

Tags: javascript, datatable

Estou querendo saber se é possível alterar a ordenação padrão de uma datatable, feita com o plugin  https://datatables.net/

Atualmente ele "nasce" ordenando pela primeira coluna, e eu queria que começasse a ordenar pela segunda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o Código:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    "scrollX": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "lengthMenu": [ [ 10, 30, 50, 100, -1], ["10","30", "50", "100","Todos"] ],
    "scrollCollapse": true,
});
```

A tabela é uma tabela comum...

```
<table id="table"> 
   <thead>
       ...
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Olhando a documentação](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html), é possível alterar a ordenação de uma DataTable usando a propriedade `order` que é um vetor de vetores de duas posições, onde a primeira indica qual a coluna (a partir do 0) e a segunda o tipo, se é crescente (asc) ou descrescente (desc), conforme exemplo a seguir:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]] //Ordena pela quarta coluna de forma descrescente
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Juro que passei batido nessa parte da doc. Valeu mesmo!